# Should i convert every single possible character in my xhtml/html code? for both encoding iso-8859-1 vs utf?

Tags: html, xhtml, unicode, character-encoding, html-entities

Should i convert every single possible charcter in my xhtml/html code? for both encoding iso-8859-1 vs utf?

If yes then is there any software to convert any needed character (which should be always in entity code) in my xhtml/html. like after complete xhtml coding in dreamweaver or in any editor i will put all code in converter and will convert only needed character to entity code.

don't want to choose and convert single-single character.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver already convert HTML entity chars..

But you can use something like this with PHP:

```
$file = 'login.php';

echo '<pre>';
echo htmlentities(file_get_contents($file));
echo '</pre>';
```

http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: how to do in dreamweaver? don't want to choose and convert single-single character.

Comment: When you're tiping the text like "look » here" it'll create a "look &raquo; here" in the source code... You can paste the text on the layout view then check the code view.

Comment: i want to type everything in code view and at end i want to convert needed characters to entity code